# ESXi: Can linked clones be on a different datastore than the parent?

Tags: vmware-esxi, clone, vdi, datastore

If I have a Local datastore that is full, and a second NFS based datastore, can I create a linked clone of a VM on the local datastore, but have the data for the clone live on the NFS datastore?  ESXi free license version 5

Comment: You can probably do this with a symbolic link on the filesystem... but my guess is that vmware discourages this type of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VMware View 4.5 and higher supports so-called tiered storage. It means that you can define different datastores used for  storing replicas, link clones, persistent disks or disposable-file disks. The advantage of such setup is speed as each datastore can have different performance characteristics (SSD vs SAS vs SATA).

When a linked-clone desktop pool is configured, you need to choose one or more datastores on which to store it. Additionally, there are two options which allows you to use tiered storage.

[image]

Comment: VmWare view seems not so "Enterprisey" as they seem to be for Desktops mostly, but this is a potential fit for the requirements, thanks.